# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, unicode, byte

I am trying to use a python script from https://github.com/clab/fast_align and get an error at this line: https://github.com/clab/fast_align/blob/cab1e9aac8d3bb02ff5ae58218d8d225a039fa11/src/force_align.py#L30

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "force_align.py", line 96, in <module>
    main()
  File "force_align.py", line 90, in main
    sys.stdout.write('{}\n'.format(aligner.align(line.strip())))
  File "force_align.py", line 30, in align
    self.fwd_align.stdin.write('{}\n'.format(line))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I have full verified that the input/output files are correct but no fix is helping solve this error. I tried `encode()` on line 30, I tried `encode('utf-8')` but nothing is helping solve the problem.

Solution 1

```
def align(self, line):
    self.fwd_align.stdin.write('{}\n'.format(line).encode())
    self.rev_align.stdin.write('{}\n'.format(line).encode())
```

Solution 2

```
def align(self, line):
    self.fwd_align.stdin.write('{}\n'.format(line).encode('utf-8'))
    self.rev_align.stdin.write('{}\n'.format(line).encode('utf-8'))
```

In both the above solution the code freezes, so I am not able to fix the encoding issue.

Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: "I tried encode() on line 30, I tried encode('utf-8') but nothing is helping solve the problem." Please indicate specifically how you tried those things (i.e. show the relevant code in context) and what happened when you tried them (any observable effect?) Anyway: if it's your code, you should be reproducing it here; otherwise you should be using Github to get support for the code.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel i have updated the details, thank you. I think is is a general python issue, not particular to a github repository.

Comment: If you wish to treat it as a general issue then the onus is still on you to provide an *example* of the code *in the question*, with proper context etc. Please see http://sscce.org for tips on creating an ideal example. Anyway - "freezes" as in, a `print` statement immediately before the lines would print and one immediately after would not? That sounds like something is seriously wrong with the inter-process communication, in which case the issue really would be specific to the code. It shouldn't be possible to have that happen when writing to an ordinary file.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thank you, yes, printing immediately after the .encode('utf-8') solution works, but then the code execution in the terminal just freezes.  The code uses some interprocess communication based file openings: https://github.com/clab/fast_align/blob/master/src/force_align.py#L59 Any solutions to try here? Thanks again for the guidance.